# How to query all subtasks with a tag at asana?

Tags: api, asana

Is there straight forward way to query all subtasks with specific tag id, or I should iterate through all subtasks and check theirs tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to query all subtasks associated with a specific tag id.

I would instead query all tasks associated with a tag id and then filter these tasks for those  with a 'parent' field not equal to null.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion.